# One-to-Many Doctrine relationship not displaying more than one entry in Symfony2 Application

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, twig

### Background

I am running a Symfony2 application for a client that tracks AEDs (defibrillators), their maintenance records, and persons responsible for their maintenance. I'm in a beta launch and have run into an issue with a one-to-many bidirectional relationship achieved with Doctrine.

The project was a conversion from a previous schema on a custom-developed framework. This means I used

### Schema

The relationship structure is a "top-down approach" where the AEDs are organized by the following:

```
Municipalities
    one-to-many-> Organizations
        one-to-many-> Locations
            one-to-many-> AEDs
                one-to-many-> Monthly Check Logs
                one-to-many-> Maintenance Records
            one-to-many-> Persons
                one-to-many-> Contact Entries
```

(This is simplified but should give you enough context for the problem I'm having.)

### The Problem

I am showing a "User Profile" where all of their associated contact entries are listed in a table. The problem is when a new entry is added, only (the newest) one shows up in the table. The others are still stored in the database but hidden for some reason.

The desired

### Debugging Steps

I cloned the production database into my staging environment and replicated the problem.

I tried forcing the fetch mode to `EAGER` and still had the same problem.

I checked the length of `person.contacts` and it outputted a value of 1.

I tried taking the runnable eager query directly into the database (as follows) and had a result of multiple entries (greater than 1):

```
SELECT 
  t0.table_id AS table_id1, 
  t0.ref_id AS ref_id2, 
  t0.person_id AS person_id3, 
  t0.contact_type AS contact_type4, 
  t0.contact_place AS contact_place5, 
  t0.contact AS contact6, 
  t0.contact_id AS contact_id7, 
  t0.person_id AS person_id8 
FROM 
  supContact t0 
WHERE 
  t0.person_id = 1490
```

I'm not sure how to proceed with debugging from here. The desired functionality is to have multiple entries show up of course.

### The Code

#### Controller Snippet

```
public function showAction($personId = 0, $organizationId = 0)
    {
        $person = $this->getDoctrine()
                        ->getRepository('AEDTracker:Genperson')
                        ->find($personId);

        return $this->render('AEDTracker:Personnel:show.html.twig', array(
            'person' => $person,
            'organizationId' => $organizationId,
        ));
    }
```

#### Twig Template Snippet

```
    {% if person.contacts is empty %}
    <tr><td colspan="100">No entries</td></tr>
    {% else %}
      {% for item in person.contacts %}
        <tr class="contact_edit" module="contact" name="{{ item.contactId }}">
           <td></td>
           <td>{{ item.contactType }}</td>
           <td>{{ item.contactPlace }}</td>
           <td>{{ item.contact }}</td>
           <td><a href="{{ path('personnelEditContact', { 'contactId': item.contactId, 'organizationId': organizationId }) }}">Edit</a></td>
        </tr>
       {% endfor %}
     {% endif %}
```

#### Genperson.orm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd">
  <entity name="AED\Tracker\Entity\Genperson" table="genPerson">
    <id name="personId" type="integer" column="person_id">
      <generator strategy="IDENTITY"/>
    </id>

    <!-- Skipped unimportant fields -->

    <one-to-many field="contacts" target-entity="Supcontact" mapped-by="person" fetch="EAGER" />
  </entity>
</doctrine-mapping>
```

#### Supcontact.orm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd">
  <entity name="AED\Tracker\Entity\Supcontact" table="supContact">
    <id name="contactId" type="integer" column="contact_id">
      <generator strategy="IDENTITY"/>
    </id>
    <field name="personId" type="integer" column="person_id" nullable="true" />

    <!-- Removed unimportant fields -->

    <many-to-one field="person" target-entity="Genperson" inversed-by="contacts">
        <join-column name="person_id" referenced-column-name="person_id" />
        <cascade>
            <cascade-persist />
            <cascade-merge />
        </cascade>
    </many-to-one>
  </entity>
</doctrine-mapping>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like a silly person, I didn't try something obvious for this fix.

There must be a bug between Symfony 2.3 and 2.4, because updating fixed this issue entirely.

For those that may ever stumble on this, to update you must download the new `composer.json` file [located here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/symfony/symfony-standard/2.4/composer.json) into the root folder of the project, then run

```
php composer.phar update
```

All dependencies will be updated, including the Symfony core and Doctrine library. Make sure you test before pushing this to your production environment.

However, oddly enough I had to keep the `fetch="EAGER"` parameter in my ORM XML files to keep the functionality working. This may not be a complete solution and someone else may have some further insight. Ideally I'd like the application to continue using lazy loading.

Comment: @Syjin I plan to, however SO has a 2-day minimum wait period before I'm able to accept my own answer. My answer also doesn't completely explain *why* Doctrine didn't work properly. I may have even missed something that caused an edge case.